# error passing JSON array to cgi script

Tags: javascript, json, perl, cgi

I'm having a javascript passing a json array to a cgi script like below.

```
getData.cgi?jsontext=JSON.strigify(array)
```

The array is below.

```
[ { "attr" : "1",
    "id"   : "1",
    "name" : "John"
   },
   { "attr" : "2",
    "id"   : "2",
    "name" : "foobar"
   }
]
```

CGI script(getData.cgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header;
print $q->param('jsontext');
```

The script works when I pass only 1 value in array. It is giving 406 error when I pass 2 or more elements like the one I mentioned above.

What can be the reason? The same script works in my loacalhost with multiple elements of array. Is there any htaccess settings problem?

Comment: I can't see any reason why changing the query string might trigger a `406` error (which should only be based on the `Accept-*` headers).

Comment: I'd speculate that you might have some horribly broken security module running on the server and you should check the error logs to see if they give any useful information about it.

Comment: A 406 error means that the data the server wants to return is incompatible with one or more of the `Accept` headers in the request. I suggest you set the `Accept` header to `*/*` in your HTTP request and see if that gets you a successful response. You can try something similar with `Accept-Charset`, `Accept-Encoding`, and `Accept-Language`. Once you get a success status you should look at the `Content-Type` header of the response to see what is *actually* being returned.

Comment: In your Javascript you probably should be passing your JSON through `encodeURIComponent` before inserting it into a URL in case it contains character with special meanings in URLs.

Comment: Is that a call to `param` in list context? Beware the new class of security vunerabilities (not all that new, really): http://blog.gerv.net/2014/10/new-class-of-vulnerability-in-perl-web-applications/